# UK and Canadian taxes

Tags: united-kingdom, canada, taxes

My son who is a Canadian citizen and pays Canadian taxes will be working in London UK for about 3 months.  He will likely be making a little more than the basic personal allowance of £12,570.  What is the best route for him to pay taxes so he is not double taxed in Canada and the UK on his UK earnings? Are there any forms he should sign so he is not double taxed?  THank you.

Comment: Generally, tax treaties exist to exclude this kind of employment.